# R: Simulate additional measurements/Bootstrap from multiple measurements

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, statistics, bootstrapping

I'm trying to simulate further measurements from existing observations in a dataframe in R. I have a dataframe of objects (A,B,C,D,...) which have been measured 3 times

As an example:

```
   1  2  3
A 10 15 12
B 20 16 24
C  4  6  8
D 10 12  9
```

I would like to simulate further observations (4th... 15th observation) from the initial 3 observations.

Observations are normally distributed and in no particular order.

I tried to draw with replacement from the initial 3 observations to generate further observations.
The `sample()` function in R worked but duplicated entire columns.
Can somebody help me to draw with replacement values from each row individually?

Ps. Since my hypothesis is that the values are normally distributed I also looked at parametric bootstrapping to generate further observations but that seems to be even more complicated.

Comment: `apply(df, 2, function(x) rnorm(100, mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x)))` to generate 100 draws from a normal distribution with a mean equal to column means and sd equal to column sd. Replace the 100 with the number of draws needed. If you need to iterate over the rows : `t(apply(df, 1, function(x) rnorm(100, mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x))))`. If you just need to sample with replacement over rows: `t(apply(df, 1, function(x) sample(x, 100, replace = TRUE)))` If something is not clear post a comment and I can provide a verbose answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I expanded my dataset by rows using by both the sample and the distribution methods. It worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
#Libraries

library(tidyverse)

#Example Data
df <-
  structure(list(V1 = c(10L, 20L, 4L, 10L),
                 V2 = c(15L, 16L, 6L,12L),
                 V3 = c(12L, 24L, 8L, 9L)),
            class = "data.frame",
            row.names = c("A","B","C","D"))

#Transpose data.frame
tdf <-
  df %>% 
  t() %>% 
  as_tibble()

#How to
tdf %>% 
  bind_rows(
    tdf %>% 
      sample_n(5,replace = TRUE) 
  )

# A tibble: 8 x 4
      A     B     C     D
  <int> <int> <int> <int>
1    10    20     4    10
2    15    16     6    12
3    12    24     8     9
4    15    16     6    12
5    15    16     6    12
6    15    16     6    12
7    10    20     4    10
8    10    20     4    10
```